# R system date with single quote

Tags: r, quote

I am trying to assign system date to a variable in R, I tried `a1 = sQuote(Sys.Date())` its not working. I see todays date with single and double quote. Not sure how to fix this issue. Any help on resolving this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the output that you require?

Comment: @RonakShah, i am looking for an output like this ' 2015-10-18'

Comment: You might try `noquote(sQuote(Sys.Date()))` if you want a "single quote",  but be careful of the class.  But why do you need this anyway?  Or actually, `shQuote()` might be what you want `print(shQuote(Sys.Date()), quote = FALSE)`

Comment: @RichardScriven, that worked perfect. I am passing this variable to db2 query :(

Comment: You're confusing R's printed output with the actual output of your function. E.g. `sQuote(Sys.Date())` is `‘2015-10-12’` - `""` are just used for printing character data in the R console. They are not actually there. E.g. `plot(0:1); text(1.5,0.5,sQuote(Sys.Date()))`

Comment: @BridgeportByronTucker If you prepare queury maybe better do `sprintf("SELECT * FROM x WHERE date>'%s'", as.character(Sys.Date()))`

Answer (score 1):

You want the date output?

```
a1 <- Sys.Date()
a1
```

yields

```
> a1
[1] "2015-10-11"
```

If you need the output as a character, then in addition to what Richard Scriven suggests (he is rather smart so I would trust what he says) why not

```
> a1 = as.character(Sys.Date())
> a1
[1] "2015-10-11"
> typeof(a1)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: OP needs it in single quotes ' 2015-10-18'

Comment: That he needs it in `single quotes` is not clear at all to me. I see him writing that he was getting date with single and double quotes. Using his code, I get the same, namely `> a1
[1] "‘2015-10-11’"` My code doesn't actually put it in any quotes. That is how R represents the object. `> typeof(a1)
[1] "double"` is my object, so if it has quotes, so do all doubles.